# 500 Server Error after saving the data in django admin

Tags: django, database, apache, django-models, http-status-code-500

My website is deployed on apache server. When I am adding image field in model. I am trying to save the object in Django admin but it is showing server error 500. But if I am removing image field in model. It is not showing any error. What should I do.

error.log

```
[Sun Feb 13 17:23:20.647087 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 120267:tid 140523953589312] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Exception ignored in: <function BaseEventLoop.__del__ at 0x7fce3e913790>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 654, in __del__
NameError: name 'ResourceWarning' is not defined
Exception ignored in: <function Local.__del__ at 0x7fce3e887ee0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nadeem/lyrics/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/local.py", line 96, in __del__
NameError: name 'TypeError' is not defined
Exception ignored in: <function Local.__del__ at 0x7fce3e887ee0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nadeem/lyrics/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/local.py", line 96, in __del__
NameError: name 'TypeError' is not defined
[Sun Feb 13 17:23:20.893734 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 120468:tid 140592717356096] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal op>
[Sun Feb 13 17:23:20.893885 2022] [core:notice] [pid 120468:tid 140592717356096] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Find where the 500 error is being logged and update your question with the error text.

Comment: In the settings.py make DEBUG=True and share the error that you see in the browser.

Comment: When debug is true it is working fine but on production when debug is false it is showing server error 500  @chandra

Comment: In the production env, make DEBUG=True. Unless you do so, it's difficult to debug.

Comment: I have updated the error log sir @iri

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.